# Linear Recurrence Using matrix exponentiation

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix

Matrix Exponentiation can be used to solve Linear Recurrence .
I know how to solve linear recurrences like :

`f(n) = f(n-k1) + f(n-k2) + ... + constant`

But i couldn't find any information on how to solve recurrences like

`f(n) = f(n-k1) + f(n-k2) + ... + n^m`

or

`f(n) = f(n-k1) + f(n-k2) + ... + n*m`

or

`f(n) = f(n-k1) + f(n-k2) + ... + k^n`
i.e. 
involving an 'n' term.

Can anyone provide me with any link or explain how to solve such recurrences
or how to form the initial matrix whose power will be used to solve the recurrence.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example. Suppose `f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2) + (n-1)^2`. We also have `n^2 = (n-1)^2 + 2(n-1) + 1` and `n = (n-1) + 1` which gives linear recursions for the algebraic terms. In matrix form,

```
|1 1 1 0 0| |f(n-1) |   | f(n) |
|1 0 0 0 0| |f(n-2) |   |f(n-1)|
|0 0 1 2 1| |(n-1)^2| = | n^2  | 
|0 0 0 1 1| | n-1   |   |  n   |
|0 0 0 0 1| |  1    |   |  1   |
```

Repeat the operation on the left side down to `n=2`.

Comment: Isn't the third row incorrect.According to it  n^2 = f(n-2) + (n-1)^2 + n-1.    It should be    | 0 0 1 2 2 |.

Comment: First row also should be | 1 1 1 2 1 |.Am I correct?

Comment: Thanks, I'll correct them.

Comment: I mainly changed the recurrence to `f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2) + (n-1)^2`.